# Can't acces to oracle from web browser

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle 11.2g and I'm trying to open the DataBase manger from browser but it dosnt work I have tried **127.0.0.1:1521/apex** and **localhost:1521/apex**
This's The **lsnrctl statut** result :

```
    C:\Users\Administrateur>lsnrctl statu

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 03-AVR. -2014 00:
06:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connexion Ó (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUT du PROCESSUS D'ECOUTE
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Date de dÚpart                       03-AVR. -2014 00:05:49
DurÚe d'activitÚ                    0 jours 0 heures 0 min. 57 sec
Niveau de trace           off
SÚcuritÚ                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Fichier journal du processus d'Úcoute             c:\app\administrateur\diag\tns
lsnr\Chlebta-PC\listener\alert\log.xml
RÚcapitulatif d'Úcoute des points d'extrÚmitÚ...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Chlebta-PC)(PORT=1521)))
Le processus d'Úcoute ne prend en charge aucun service
La commande a rÚussi
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows->all programs->oracle home->Database Control-orcl

Answer (score 0):

go to start -> all programs -> oracle database express edition -> get started

and then you will directed to the web browser automatically ...

you will see .. few red tabs ... such as storage .. session ... and application express ...

click on application express ... login using sys and password using while installing ....
then create application express login id and password which you can create new as well as use the existing one .. after creation you will directed to a page where you will be asked workspace , username, password ... enter the one you created or existing one and login with that . remember that you still have to create the workspace even if you already can access the database with the same username and password through sql*plus..